# Borel-Cantelli Application to show a set has measure $0$ my attempt was incorrect

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-measure, borel-cantelli-lemmas

Let $\alpha > 2$ be a real number. Define

$$E = \{x \in [0,1] \ s.t. \ |x - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^{\alpha}} \ \forall p,q\}$$
Prove $m(E) = 0$

Hint: fix $p,q$ and calculate the measure of that set. Apply Borel-Cantelli.

Well, this hint has not gotten me too far. If I let $p = q = 1$, I'd get

$|x - 1| < 1$

$x - 1 < 1 \to x < 2$

$-(x - 1) < 1 \to 1 - x < 1 \to 0 < x$

$m((0,2)) = 2 - 0 = 2$ which is not equal to $0$. Did I make a mistake here?

For the application of Borel Cantelli, here is my attempt:

Let $E_i = \{x \ s.t. \ |x - \frac{p_i}{q_i}| < \frac{1}{q^{\alpha}}\}$

This is countable because $\frac{p_i}{q_i}$ is rational and the rationals are countable

Then, $x \in [\frac{p_i}{q_i} - \frac{1}{q^{\alpha}}, \frac{p_i}{q_i} + \frac{1}{q^{\alpha}}]$

So, $\sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} m(E_i) = \sum_{i = 1}^{\infty} 2 * \frac{1}{q^{\alpha}} < \infty$

Therefore, Borel-Cantelli applies, and the set is of measure $0$.

I must have done something terribly wrong here because my instructor was angry when I turned this part in (I didn't submit the (0,2) error because that one was obviously a mistake). This part alone made him noticeably upset, so I must be making a terrible mistake. From looking at this though, I really don't see where I went wrong. Can anyone clear up my confusion here?

Edit: I am still stuck. Is anyone able to help?

Edit 2: Still have not been able to solve this. The class is well over now, but I have still been trying to solve some questions on the side. Can anyone solve this one so I can take note of it?

Comment: Hint: let $E_{p,q}=\{x \in [0,1] \ s.t. \ |x - \frac{p}{q}| < \frac{1}{q^{\alpha}}\}.$ Then, $m(E)\le\sum_{p,q}m(E_{p,q})\le \sum\frac{1}{q^2}$

Comment: can you elaborate a bit? I'm not quite seeing it from there. If you don't want to give a full answer, could you maybe explain your hint a bit better? I'd be ok with that, and I'd let you know if it isn't clicking still.

Comment: For fixed $p,q$ if $x\in E_{p,q}$ then its distance from $p/q$ is less than $1/q^2.$ That is, $E_{p,q}$ is contained in the symmetric interval of length $2/q^2$ about $p/q.$ But $E\subseteq \bigcup_{p,q}E_{p,q}$ so...

Comment: Hmm. I'm still not quite seeing how to proceed. I'm sorry about that. I think I see what you're saying here, but I don't know how that would help me.

Comment: @Matematleta just wanted to see if you saw my last reply. I've looked at this a bit more, and I am still not sure how to proceed.

Comment: I’m confused about the $\forall p,q$.  Is there an $x \in [0,1]$ s.t. $ \ |x - \frac{1}{5}| < \frac{1}{5^{\alpha}} $ and $ \ |x - \frac{4}{5}| < \frac{1}{5^{\alpha}} $?

Comment: [Here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Liouville_number#Irrationality_measure) is a Wikipedia article that may be useful to you

Comment: @OliverDiaz I don't know what a Liouville number is. I see it relates here, but there's no proof given of this problem. I just really want someone to help me with this specific problem, I've been stuck for so long and I have an exam tomorrow. I just want something to study,

Comment: @Joe what do you mean? I stated the problem as it was given.

Comment: Using the fact $\sum\frac{1}{q^2}$ converges, together with Borel-Cantelli, what can you say about elements of the $E_{p,q}?

Comment: @Matematleta I am not sure. How does $\sum \frac{1}{q^2}$ play a role here? We are given $\frac{1}{q^{\alpha}}$, not $\alpha = 2$.

Comment: $\alpha>2$ so the series converges.

Comment: I’m saying that it seems to me like $E$ is defined to be the set of all $x \in [0,1]$ s.t. $\forall p,q$ (presumably in $\mathbb{N}$)$$\left| x- \frac{p}{q} \right| < \frac{1}{q^\alpha}$$but I don’t see how any $x$ satisfies that for $p=1,q=5$ and for $p=4,q=5$. Am I misunderstanding the definition of $E$?

Comment: @Matematleta ah ok cool. By p-series. So what does that mean though in relation to this problem?

Comment: @Joe I'm not sure. This is just how the problem was given to me

Comment: I hope the exam went well. If you eventually understand $E$ well enough to explain the answer to the question in my comment, and post it, I’ll upvote the answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $F$ be the set of those $x\in [0,1]$ for which there exist infinitely many $(p,q)\in \Bbb N^2$ satisfying $|x-p/q|<1/q^{\alpha}.$ Clearly $E\subseteq F$. We show $m(F)=0$.

For $n\in \Bbb N$ let $S_n=\cup \{(j/n-1/n^{\alpha},\,j/n+1/n^{\alpha}): n\ge j\in\Bbb N_0\}.$

For $n'\in \Bbb N$ let $T_{n'}=\cup \{S_n:n\ge n'\}.$

Then $x\in F\implies x\in\cap \{T_{n'}:n'\in \Bbb N\}.$

We have $m(S_n)\le 2(n+1)/n^{\alpha}\le 4/n^{\alpha - 1}.$

Therefore $m(T_{n'})\le \sum_{n=n'}^{\infty}4/n^{\alpha-1}=O(1/n'^{(\alpha-2}) =o(1)$ as $n'\to\infty.$

So $m(F)=0$ because $F\subseteq T_{n'}$ for every $n'.$

Comment: More generally let $G$ be the set of those $x\in\Bbb R$ for which there exist $a>2$ and $k>0$ and infinitely many $(p,q)\in \Bbb Z\times \Bbb N$ satisfying $|x-p/q|<k/q^a.$ Then $m(G)=0$ by similar methods. A deep result by Roth (circa 1950) is that every $x\in G\setminus\Bbb Q$ is transcendental over $\Bbb Q$.